# js trigger(create) when i do "add to home" don't work

Tags: jquery, triggers, safari

i do a script like this:

```
$("#last").bind("change", function() {
    var myselect = document.getElementsByTagName("select");
    var numselect = myselect.length;
    var oldid = "select-" + numselect;
    var newidslider = "slider-" + (numselect + 1);
    $('#last').attr('name', oldid);
    $('#last').attr('id', oldid);
    $('#last').selectmenu("refresh", true);
    $('#selects').append('<label for="last" class="select">scegli personaggio:</label><select name="last" id="last"><option value="pippo">pippo</option><option value="pluto">pluto</option><option value="paperino">paperino</option><option value="topolino">topolino</option></select><div class="spazio"></div><input type="range" name="' + newidslider + '" id="' + newidslider + '" value="50" min="0" max="100"/>').trigger('create');
});
```

it work fine when i use app safari mobile or chrome mobile, but when i visit my site after i "added to home screen" the js doesn't work!
Anyone does know this problem! i'm stuck in this situation!
thanks for attentions!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not sure about anything to do with mobile or "add to homescreen", but there are a couple of lines in that code that may cause a problem.  I am just reading the code, I haven't run it, so I could be wrong.

```
$('#last').selectmenu("refresh", true);
```

That will not find any element to operate on, since the previous line has changed the item's ID so that it is not "last" anymore.

```
$('#selects').append(.....
```

is creating a new element with the ID "last", but if you want that to also get the onChange function, you will have to attach it again.  The original bind() call only operates on the item that had the ID "last" at the time it was run.

Comment: i have found pheraps where is the problem but i don't know how to solve.
the page in which there is the script over is reached by an other page that is my homepage. When i go there from my homepage with firebug i see that code of my script doesn't appear in the page. But if i refresh the page with browser button, magically the code of script appear in the line of html page and all works fine.
Why there is this behaviour??

Comment: How is the script being included in the 2nd page (not the homepage)?  Can you post the code or a link to the page itself?

Comment: you are right the script must be also in the previous page! sorry but i'm newbie in js :9

Answer (score 1):

**Delegate the event**

```
$("#last").bind("change" , function() {
```

supposed to be

```
$("body").on("change" ,"#last" , function() {
```

The element is not available in the DOM when the event handler is associated.. Delegating the event to a static parent should solve your problem..

Comment: i have found pheraps where is the problem but i don't know how to solve.
the page in which there is the script over is reached by an other page that is my homepage. When i go there from my homepage with firebug i see that code of my script doesn't appear in the page. But if i refresh the page with browser button, magically the code of script appear in the line of html page and all works fine.
Why there is this behaviour??